# How to capture a server side web api call in chrome dev tools

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-chrome-devtools

I have got a web application with the following topology.

A (Web application) ---calls---> B (Local Web Api) ---calls---> C (Remote Web Api)

I am trying to capture the traffic from B to C in chrome DEV tools - network tab, but nothing is logged. It only showing one server request. I want to see the subsequent calls made by that server request. Is it possible?

B is a web site hosted locally on my dev box in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently only debugging your client side app, so DevTools will only show the single request to your local web API. In order to debug the middle layer, you need to debug the API.

If you are using Node JS for this, you can use the v8 inspector by running `node --inspect` and then use the debugging URL to open up DevTools. Alternatively you can fallback to using [Node Inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector)

If you are using .NET Web API, you can use the debugger in Visual Studio to see the subsequent calls to the remote API, but [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) is a very handy tool as well, especially for mocking.